# How to get the client port in RequestHandler?

Tags: tornado

In the `RequestHandler` we can use `self.request.remote_ip` to get the client ip address, but how to get the client port?

And, if the client side implemented with `tornado.simple_httpclient.SimpleAsyncHTTPClient`, how to get the port for this connection?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want the client port? There's not currently a supported interface for this although I think `self.request.connection.stream.socket.getpeername()` will work (untested).

I don't understand your second question about "request port" in `SimpleAsyncHTTPClient`.

Comment: Um, in other word, that is the port number for this connection.

Comment: The client-side port is not exposed in any way in AsyncHTTPClient.

Comment: self.request.connection.stream.socket.getpeername() works

Comment: @BenDarnell if you could look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35492062/get-client-port-number-using-tornado-using-websockets would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

try `self.request.connection.context.address` in `open` when `self.request.connection.stream` is `None`.
Example output: `('127.0.0.1', 56209)`