# Get client port number using tornado using WebSockets

Tags: websocket, tornado

I can get client ip:

```
self.request.remote_ip
```

I can also get client port number from RequestHandler:

```
self.request.connection.stream.socket.getpeername()[1]
```

(thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33155831/how-to-get-the-client-port-in-requesthandler))

But what about client port number from WebSocket?

I can't find anything on how to do this in the docs.  I have had a long look through the source but still can't figure out where it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in [How to get the client port in RequestHandler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33155831/how-to-get-the-client-port-in-requesthandler), the first question is why do you want this?

In a websocket handler, the equivalent to the code you've posted above is `self.stream.socket.getpeername()[1]`.

Comment: Great thanks a million!  The use case here is multiple devices are connected to a server.  When a new device connects, it is added to a map, and its ip address is used as the key.  If two devices are connected from the same wireless network, the ip isn't enough (since these two devices show up as having the same ip - that of the proxy/NAT), but using an ip:port combination we have a unique address.  Would you suggest doing this a different way?

Comment: The client port doesn't identify a user/device, it identifies a connection. If the same device reconnects it (probably) won't have the same port again. If you want to identify a user or device, you'll have to use something like a cookie. If you only want to identify the connection, then the client `ip:port` is one way to get a unique identifier, but there are lots of others. The easiest thing is to just use `self` (i.e. the `WebSocketHandler` instance itself) as your map key.

Comment: Ah yes, self as the key is a neater solution, thanks.